# bootstrap responsive broken

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

After cloning my git repo, my app was broken. I fixed it ( Deleted the bootstrap_and_overrides.css.less ) to the point where I can actually see the pages now but the drop down lists and tabs are broken. This makes me think the bootstrap-responsive, for some reason, isn't being loaded. Below is what I feel are the culprits.

**Gemfile**

```
gem 'rails', '~> 3.2.6'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 2.0.4.0'
gem 'less', '~> 2.2.0'
```

**application.js**

```
//= require bootstrap
//= require_tree .
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui
```

**bootstrap_and_overrides.css.scss**

```
$iconSpritePath: image-path('/glyphicons-halflings.png'); 
$iconWhiteSpritePath: image-path('glyphicons-halflings-white.png'); 
$navbarBackground: #555; 
$navbarBackgroundHighlight: #888; 
$navbarText: #eee; 
$navbarLinkColor: #eee; 

@import "bootstrap"; 
body { padding-top: 60px; } 
@import "bootstrap-responsive";
```

Eek, help please?

Comment: Is this just a dumb question? Am I not clear enough? Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found out the answer if anyone comes across this, hopefully it will help. What was going on was I had included the bootstrap-responsive.css which was being loaded twice. It's already included in my bootstrap_and_overrides.css.scss file. I deleted the extra css file that was not needed and blamo it works.

Answer (score 1):

uninstall old gem `'bootstrap-sass', '~> 2.0.4.0'` and install the new version `gem "bootstrap-sass", "~> 2.2.2.0"`

If something of your app is broken, you must change the css code on your `bootstrap_and_overrides.css` something like:

```
// Set the correct sprite paths
$iconSpritePath: asset-url('glyphicons-halflings.png', image);
$iconWhiteSpritePath: asset-url("glyphicons-halflings-white.png", image);

@import "bootstrap";

/* new design.................................................................................*/
```

If you are customized this file previously, you have restore each error from `bootstrap_and_overrides.css` file

Comment: I updated gems. Changed sprite paths. Still doesn't work. What do you mean restore each error? There aren't really errors just broken functionality.  [link](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#navs)[/link] is what is broken.

Comment: Do you mean that your app is not loading the bootstrap gem?. I mean, you can see some css or javascript of twitter bootstrap on your app loaded?

Comment: Yes, I can see css and javascript is working. It's just specifically the bootstrap responsive things like Tabbable nav and bootstrap-collapse

Comment: checking with @bdares solution!

Comment: this answer helped me to fix my problem !!thanks u havent got any green yet?

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking you're seeing that the bootstrap javascript components aren't working correctly.

This is because bootstrap's js components depend on jQuery, and those are being included *after* bootstrap, not before.  Change your order of inclusion (and include jquery):

**application.js**

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui
//= require bootstrap
//= require_tree .
```

Comment: If I move require_tree after jquery my javascript is broken. When it's after bootstrap the problem still persists. For example /some/page I click on my collapsible and it says /some/page/#collapsableOne but nothing is expanded